# Error: locals[0] does not appear to be a `module` object with Hot Module replacement API enabled

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to start my app on node server and I get error:

Uncaught Error: locals[0] does not appear to be a `module` object with Hot Module replacement API enabled. You should disable react-transform-hmr in production by using `env` section in Babel configuration. I have followed the link privided:

```
{
"presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"],
"env": {
// only enable it when process.env.NODE_ENV is 'development' or undefined
"development": {
  "plugins": [["react-transform", {
    "transforms": [{
      "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
      // if you use React Native, pass "react-native" instead:
      "imports": ["react"],
      // this is important for Webpack HMR:
      "locals": ["module"]
    }]
    // note: you can put more transforms into array
    // this is just one of them!
  }]]
 }
}
}
```

Now, how can I do it? By commenting out or changing some lines?